# How to tighten this unusual faucet nut?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet

[image]This is a 4 year old faucet, and it has a nut/extension that I have not seen before. The tip is plastic. I checked with local HD, and they did not have an answer either. I appreciate your help. [image]

Comment: I believe those are caps to protect the lines.  Pull them off to see what you have underneath.

Comment: You may need to twist them off rather than pull them off, if they're threaded... But, yeah, removing the black pieces looks like the first step.

Comment: @Ruskes: Hot and cold in, separate spray head out, hence three tubes. I could always be wrong, but that looks like the underside of a kitchen faucet to me.  And the OP says it's a faucet. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: Thanks All. @RMDman I removed the plastic cover, and it looks like it is just threaded. I added a second picture. I am still unsure how to tighten this.

Comment: It appears they have to be tightened from the other side.  However you can try to grip the threaded stubs with pilers and turn them at a risk of damaging the threads and having more issues later.

Comment: Clearly tightened from the other side, under the cover of the faucet, remove the cover and you will see it

Comment: if not accessible, cut a slot (screwdriver size in the screws) and use screwdriver to tighten

Comment: Thank you All. Yes, it was the other side. I removed the faucet, and it was right there. For the record, this is a Kraus faucet, and I followed the Step 2, and Step 1 of this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pfeofClXcA

Comment: Once again, your help has been very MUCH appreciated. Happy Holidays!!!